# Jquery - Select <tr> correctly

Tags: jquery

I have this structure (see below) and I want to create a function when the user clicks on any `<td>` at the table row....

**This is my HTML Code**

```
<table class="player_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: black; color:#fad32b;">
            <td style="width:32%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Playername</td>
            <td style="width:20%">Club</td>
            <td style="width:9%">Pos.</td>
            <td style="width:15%">Points</td>
            <td style="width:9%">Costs</td>
        </tr>
```

And this is my **Jquery** code, but it doesn't work correctly

```
$(window).load(function() {    
    $(".player_table tbody tr").children().click(function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: why not `$(".player_table tbody tr").click`

Comment: why do you have `.children()` when you want to click tr only

Comment: Remove `children()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $("table > tbody ").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    console.log( this, " at index: ",  $(this).index() );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

would that do?

Comment: why do you need to select the TRs in the delegate, they are not generated on the fly

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev - I do not understand your question. This is best-practice and should always be done to minimize events-attachment to multiple elements

Comment: well I did not know that this is worse when the elements are not changing -> $("table > tbody tr").on(... do you have any article on that? Thanks

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev - you don't need an article, this is very fundamental, when a person starts learning client-side they learn how to bind events, each event obviously is bound on the element, and takes memory and resources, so for example, if you have a table with 1000 rows, you wouldn't want to bind a 1000 event listeners right? that is not how a programmer should handle memory in a code, but one should consider all memory aspects on each line of code written.

Comment: you are overthinking this, also are you 100% familiar with the implementation of jquery's on (bind and delegate) and click.. I doubt that, thanks anyway

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev - I have been using jQuery since 2005 and am familiar with the source code, have read countless change logs over the years and countless articles on how these things work, so you can either trust me or google yourself. as I said, this is so basic it's the very first thing you learn, I'm not "overthinking" anything. best practice is best practice. if you are a client-side developer than you should know how the DOM works in relation to events binding.

Comment: if n = 1000, starting from attaching the event handlers ~100 milliseconds more and the total amount of memory 4-5 megabytes more I do not think that this is of such critical importance for a basic usage case, I am sure that you are not making this up just when we speak for 10 to hundred elements it does not matter cheers and no hard feelings

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev - best practice is best practice, especially if it doesn't take you any more time than writing it wrongly. One must adopt as many small good habits so when they face bigger ones, adaptation would be easier. If you keep ignoring best practice on tiny matters you will soon find yourself ignoring them on larger issues. In life as well in code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help and suggestions, but this helped me out:

```
$(window).load(function() {    
    $(".player_table").on('click', 'td', function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```